# Can't debug intellij plugin - invalid initial heap size

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jvm-arguments

I'm developing an intellij plugin and when i'm trying to run the plugin (or debug it) i keep getting the following error:

> Could not create the Java virtual machine. Invalid initial heap size:
>   -Xms128m

The JVM parameters in the Run\Debug configurations are (by default):

> -Xms128m
>   -Xmx512m
>   -XX:MaxPermSize=250m
>   -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64m
>   -XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing
>   -ea
>   -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false

So eventually I can't debug or run my code.

Comment: Have you tried setting `-Xms` to a higher value?

Comment: @weltraumpirat yes, tried to increas\decrease the value

Comment: Usually this is because you've made a typo in the options. Hard to tell from your pasted options. I'd try to remove all if them and entering/addung them one at the time again and make sure there's no spaces or things like that in the wrong places.

Answer (score 1):

JVM is unhappy because there are newline characters between options.
You can confirm this by copy-pasting *VM Options* into a text editor.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem today. I solved this problem by making the  checked and select the IDEA Plugin Sdk。My Idea version is 11.1.5. you can try it..